# For loop with d3.line function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am encountering a strange behavior within for loop with d3.line function. 
This is what the loop looks like:

```
for (zzz = 0; zzz < 3; zzz++) {
    lines = d3.line()
        .x(function(d,i) { console.log(zzz); x([1,2,3]) })
        .y(function(d,i) { console.log(zzz); y([1,2,3]) });
}
```

Normally, I would expect the `console.log` of this to look like

```
0
1
2
```

instead I am getting

```
3
3
3
```

I spent days trying to figure out why... Can anyone help?

[Here is a jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrkwspt6/). It has bare minimum in it to generate console output.

Answer (score 1):

This block:

```
for (zzz = 0; zzz < 3; zzz++) {
    lines = d3.line()
        .x(function(d,i) { console.log(zzz); x([1,2,3]) })
        .y(function(d,i) { console.log(zzz); y([1,2,3]) });
}
```

Doesn't log anything. Check this demo:

```js
for (zzz = 0; zzz < 3; zzz++) {
  console.log("Outside d3.line, zzz is " + zzz);
  lines = d3.line()
      .x(function(d,i){console.log("Inside d3.line nothing is printed!");x([1,2,3]) })
      .y(function(d,i){console.log("Inside d3.line nothing is printed!");y([1,2,3]) });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

The reason is that `d3.line()` is not being called (and, thus, will not print anything in the console). `d3.line()` is only called when you actually append the path (using `lines`). By that time, the `for` loop has finished and `zzz` is 3 (if you used `let`, it'd be `2` instead).

Also, the fact that you get `3` three times is just a coincidence, it has nothing to do with the fact that the `for` loop goes from 0 to 2 (looping three times), but only with the fact that you pass an array with three values to `lines` in your fiddle: `lines([1, 2, 3])`. In the following demo, it will print `zzz` just once for each function:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body");
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 100]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([100, 0]);

for (zzz = 0; zzz < 3; zzz++) {
  lines = d3.line()
  .x(function(d,i) { console.log("first console.log: " + zzz); x([1,2,3]) })
  .y(function(d,i) { console.log("second console.log: " + zzz); y([1,2,3]) });
}

svg.append("path").attr("d", lines([1]));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

So, in a nutshell, you are just defining `lines` inside a `for` loop.